# Replacing non-ascii character character non-obtrusively between xml tags

Tags: perl

I have an XML string in the following format that I need to tidy up before parsing it as follows, otherwise it fails with the error "Input is not proper UTF-8; indicate encoding":

```
my $xml_parsed_mess = XML::LibXML->new() -> parse_string($xml_mess);
```

The string is as follows:

```
my $xml_mess = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><message><tag1>இந்தியாtest123</tag1><tag2>网络test网络</tag2><tag3>i am clean</tag3><tag4>do not worry about me</tag4></message></xml>"
```

I don't want to convert the entire string to UTF-8, but what I want to do is clean specific tags in the string, for example in this instance:

```
<tag1>இந்தியாtest123</tag1> -> <tag1>test123</tag1>
```

I know that the command to do this is:

```
$xml_mess =~ s/[[:^ascii:]]+/ /g;
```

But how do I target the contents of the specific fields such as `<tag1>???</tag1>, <tag2>????</tag2>`.

I know I can change the contents as follows:

```
$xml_mess =~ s|<tag1>test</tag1>|<tag1>testing</tag1>
```

But how do I run this command against the contents of the tag `$xml_mess =~ s/[[:^ascii:]]+/ /g;` instead of replacing the contents - and subsequently update $xml_mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("a.xml");

for my $text_node ($doc->findnodes("/message/tag1/text()")) {
   $text_node->setData(
      $text_node->getData() =~ s/[[:^ascii:]]+/ /rg
   );
}

print $doc->toString;
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><message><tag1>இந்தியாtest123</tag1><tag2>网络test网络</tag2><tag3>i am clean</tag3><tag4>do not worry about me</tag4></message>
```

It produces

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><message><tag1> test123</tag1><tag2>网络test网络</tag2><tag3>i am clean</tag3><tag4>do not worry about me</tag4></message>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with regular expressions (without XML::LibXML)?

Comment: No, not accurately. You need a parser, and while one could write a parser that based around regex matches (note the plural), there's no point in writing another XML parser.

Comment: How would the above be written so that it parses a string instead of a file at this line `my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("a.xml");`

Comment: See your own question